# CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have built a rss news app. It is working fine upto some point with some bugs. Problem is content provider is not adding new News for some rss feeds and getting Cursor finalized without prior close() error in logs. I am refreshing the feed in background IntentService. Need to improve performance if possible.

```
private int refreshLocalFeed(Feeds feeds) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {

    LogMessage.d("feed refresh:", feeds.getCategoryId() + " : " + feeds.getName());
    Call<RSSFeed2> call = api.loadOwnRssFeed(feeds.getUrl());
    ContentResolver cr = MyApp.getAppContext().getContentResolver();
    int success = 0;
    try {
        Response<RSSFeed2> response = call.execute();
        RSSFeed2 rssFeed = response.body();
        if (rssFeed != null) {
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
            Collections.reverse(rssFeed.getArticleList());
            for (Article article : rssFeed.getArticleList()) {

                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = cr.query(DbContract.EntryColumns.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{DbContract.EntryColumns._ID}, DbContract.EntryColumns.CATEGORYID + "=? AND " + DbContract.EntryColumns.LINK + "=?",
                            new String[]{feeds.getCategoryId(), article.getLink()}, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.TITLE, article.getTitle());
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.DESCRIPTION, article.getDescription());
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.DATE, article.getPubDate());
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.AUTHOR, getString(R.string.app_name));
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.FETCH_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.CATEGORYID, feeds.getCategoryId());
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.GUID, article.getGuid());

                String alternateImageUrl = getImageUrl(article.getDescription());
                if (article.getThumbnail() != null && !article.getThumbnail().isEmpty()) {
                    values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.IMAGE_URL, article.getThumbnail());
                } else if (!alternateImageUrl.isEmpty()) {
                    values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.IMAGE_URL, getImageUrl(article.getDescription()));
                }
                values.put(DbContract.EntryColumns.LINK, article.getLink());

                if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
                    operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(DbContract.EntryColumns.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withSelection(DbContract.EntryColumns._ID, new String[]{String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbContract.EntryColumns._ID)))})
                            .withValues(values)
                            .build());
                    c.close();
                } else {
                    operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(DbContract.EntryColumns.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValues(values)
                            .build());

                }
            }
            ContentProviderResult[] results = cr.applyBatch(DbContract.AUTHORITY, operations);
            for (ContentProviderResult result : results) {
                if (result.uri != null) {
                    success++;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return success;
}
```

**edit**

```
if (c != null) {
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(DbContract.EntryColumns.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withSelection(DbContract.EntryColumns._ID, new String[]{String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbContract.EntryColumns._ID)))})
                                .withValues(values)
                                .build());
    }
    c.close();
} else {
        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(DbContract.EntryColumns.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValues(values)
                            .build());
    }
```

Comment: You only close the cursor if rows are extracted i.e. `c.getCount() > 0`, you should always close a cursor when done with it. Noting that a cursor with no rows is still a valid cursor that should be closed.

Comment: @MikeT, I have updated the code. Still it gives same error in log.

Comment: @MikeT, can insert and update both be done in    ContentResolver.applyBatch(operationslist)?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never used a ContentResolver. However if you are doing multiple changes then you may consider enclosing them in a transaction using db.beginTransaction() .... do you stuff, if stuff worked OK db.setTransactionSuccessful() and either OK or not db.endTransaction().